# Paypal Return Message 3005 on Sandbox Account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, recurring-billing

I am using Paypal sandbox for recurring payment system. my  express check out payment for initial payment is working proper and also create Recurring Payments Profile in sandbox. But when i searching the transaction i am getting the below error.

Sorry — your last action could not be completed

```
If you were making a purchase or sending money, we recommend that you check both your PayPal account and your email for a transaction confirmation after 30 minutes.
```

If you came to this page from another website, please return to that site (don't use your browser's Back button) and restart your activity.

If you came from PayPal's website, click the PayPal logo in the upper-left corner to return to our home page and restart your activity. You might have to log in again.
We are sorry, we are experiencing temporary difficulties. Please try again later. If this error occurred while making a payment, avoid duplicate payments by checking your Account Overview before resending a payment.

For some browsers, this problem can be resolved by clearing or deleting cookies.

Message 3005

I have also enable recurring payment in seller account.